# Использование функции has_tag: как если без elseif?

Tags: wordpress

Вопрос по WordPress.

Можно ли на странице записи (single post) отобразить текст, который изменяется в зависимости от того, какой тег задан у записи. Если запись относится к определенному ТЕГУ,  который указан в заданном ассоциативном массиве, то должен отображаться соответствующий этому тегу ТЕКСТ. Я знаю, в WordPress есть функция `has_tag()`, которая проверяет, относится ли тег к данной записи.

Например,

```
if ( has_tag('TAGNAME') ) {
<p>выводиться  TEXT для тега TAGNAME </p>

elseif ( has_tag('TAGNAME1') ) {
<p>выводиться TEXT1 для тега TAGNAME1 </p>
```

и так далее (везде разные теги и тексты)

Но как сделать это программно? Не писать же каждый раз конструкции elseif?! Тем более когда тегов много. Нельзя ли всё это представить в виде массива?

```
 $test = array('TAGNAME' => 'TEXT',
 'TAGNAME1' => 'TEXT1')
```

И чтобы потом осуществлялась проверка по тегу через метод `has_tag`, и выводился нужный текст? Но как примерно это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @user700: вы же сами всё написали! Ассоциативный массив -- хорошая идея, лучше, чем дерево if'ов или switch.

Answer (score 3):

switch, case, default, break

Пример:

```
switch ($_GET['test']) {
case 0: // if (0==$_GET['test']) {
echo "test";
break; // }
case 1: //} else if (1==$_GET['test']) {
echo "test 1";
break; // }
case 2: //} else if (2==$_GET['test'])
echo "test 2"; 
break; // }
default: //} else {
echo "ignore";
break; // }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Или так:

```
 <?php
    $spectags = array('tagname1' => 'Some text', 'tagname2' => 'Another text'); //наш массив особых тегов с текстом
    $posttags = get_the_tags(); //все теги текушего поста в массивв
    if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {  //для каждого провряем, не входит ли в какую-то из категорий вывода
        if (array_key_exists($tag->name, $spectags)) {
        // или if (isset($spectags[$tag->name])) {
        // так, наверное, даже лучше будет
          echo '<p>' . $spectags[$tag->name] . '</p>';
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда я думал, что можно как-то массово это сделать, не знаю как, например создать ассоциативный массив и шаблон switch-case-echo-break, и циклом сформировать в итоге код, т.е. чтобы не самому заполнять все это

Comment: Посмотрите такой вариант, не знаю, на сколько он оптимален

Answer (score 1):

```
$tags = array('tagname' => 'tagvalue');

foreach($tags as $k => $v) {
    if(has_tag($k))
       echo $v;
}
```

Так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$tag2text = array('tag1' => 'text1', 'tag2' => 'text2');

function getTextForTag($tag)
{
    if (array_key_exists($tag, $tag2text))
        return $tag2text[$tag];
    // report error or return default text or whatever
}

function getTextsForTags($tags)
{
    return array_map("getTextForTag", $tags);
}
```